# ReflectionException in compiled.php line 1049: Class App\Http\Controllers\User does not exist

Tags: laravel-5

i test laravel 5 that i have controller name Usercontroller.php have code:

```
  class UserController extends Controller

    {

    protected $user = null;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;    
    } 

   public function allUsers()
   {
       return $this->user->allUsers();

   }    
    }
```

and i create model name user.php have code:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function allUsers()
    {
        return self::all(); 
    }

}
```

when i run it show error like below

```
ReflectionException in compiled.php line 1049: Class App\Http\Controllers\User does not exist
```

please help me solve about this problem, thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `User` model is found in the namespace `App` and you have to reference it like that:

```
public function __construct(\App\User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;    
}
```

Or add an import statement at the top:

```
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
```